# UICollectionView section index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

If while scrolling header section in UICollectionview rose above navigationitem how can I know the index of the header section which is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use view.window property if its nil it means its not visible. 
Since Collection view re-uses views you would like to check which last header view is visible 
instead and subtract one .

```
1) For the UIViews which are visible get the min index.
2) All the view above it are not visible.
```